# Can we add Non-Black field validation in js when creating record using force:createRecord

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I have created a component which has a button. onclick event on the button navigates to record create page . I have used force:createRecord for this. However I want to add a validation in js that one of the fields cannot be blank. Is this possible? I dont want to create a validation rule for this.I want the validation to be handled in componenet.

Comment: Looks like this is not possible and I will have to create a custom component to create a record and then I can add validations in js controller. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** perform any validations on your component, if you are using [force:createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation). The event once fired opens the "standard" create screen and that you don't have any control on that thereafter.

Refer to this excerpt from the documentation:

> Firing the force:createRecord event tells the app to use the standard create record page. You can’t catch errors that occur there, or alter the create page interface or behavior, for example, to show an improved error message. For this reason, it’s essential to perform access checks in your own code, before firing the event.